# flutter tflite shape error TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:1) with shape [1, 10] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4]

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection, tflite

i have converted my ssd mobilenet v2 pb file to tflite using this code. Please check the code and help me to bring this.

this is the code for pb to tflite

```
command = "tflite_convert \
--saved_model_dir={} \
--output_file={} \
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 \
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor \
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
--inference_type=FLOAT \
--allow_custom_ops".format(FROZEN_TFLITE_PATH, TFLITE_MODEL, )
```

getting this Error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:1) with shape [1, 10] to a Java object with shape [1, 10, 4].
```

Comment: Have you found any solution?